# Зависание сайта при свободной памяти и процессоре

Tags: linux, сервер, centos, apache2

Такая проблема!
Сайт крутится на VDS: Centos 7 (от BitrixVM) + php 7.1 + apache 2.4 (prefork) + nginx.
Уже как 2 недели бывают краткосрочные зависания сайта (скорее всего apache2) (не зависит от времени суток и дня недели)
при этом:

- Оперативки более чем достаточно (200-300 мб свободно, так почти всегда), swap почти весь свободен, процессор в моменты зависания по большей части свободен (не выше 7% загрузка), диск не нагружен.
- В логах apache, nginx, mysql пусто, без ошибок.
- DDOS-атаки не видно,всплеска посещаемости нет.

Зависание как будто от тяжёлого процесса апач и ничего больше не дает делать, но при этом зависают сессии всех пользователей, а не только моя. Это при prefork! Nginx в этот момент работает штатно и неавторизованным пользователям отдаётся сайт из кэша.

В момент зависания в списке запущенных процессов  httpd пропадает, как будто не запущен, а попытка его перезапуска командой systemctl restart httpd, не приносит результата, зависает на 1-2 минуты, как будто тяжелый процесс держит апач. Перезапуск апача не гарантирует, что работа восстановится, бывает что через минуту все повторяется снова.

Служба поддержки VDS таймвеба бегло всё проверила и тоже ничего не нашла.
Куда копать? 
Помогите!

Скрин atop в момент зависания и скрин с htop когда все работает хорошо:
[image: скрин с atop]
[image: скрин с htop]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99960/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил. 
Дело было в Bitrix CMS, а именно нашел функцию SessionTable::lock, которая шлет запросы GET_LOCK("***", 60) в базу.
Не знаю почему в документации о ней мало что написано.
Не совсем понятно когда она срабатывает, но у меня подозрение что когда число одновременных запросов к MySQL подбирается к лимиту.
В результате получаем блокировку сайта на 1 минуту и пустые логи.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: А как решили-то? Запретили блокировку, что ли? ;)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev лучшее решение в данном случае не использовать Bitrix CMS.

Comment: @zalex очевидно, что наилучшее решение — вообще никогда его не использовать, но в этом вопросе его использование как бы данность...

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev, переписал часть запросов, которые часто посылаются к БД на чистом PHP, минуя CMS.